# Signup form data not showing up in DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried changing the code to this so it connects to the DB before anything else but now it just lingers on verify.php, no redirect, no data being sent to DB.

```
        <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
 # connect to the database here
$host="XXXXXXX"; // Host name 
   $username="XXXX"; // Mysql username 
   $password="XXXX"; // Mysql password 
  $db_name="XXXX"; // Database name 

   mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect for insert"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB to insert data");

    $user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
    $fname =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
     $lname =     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']); 
    $email =     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
     $user_password =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 

     $insert_query = "INSERT INTO teachers(`user_name`,`fname`,`lname`,`email`,`password`) 
    VALUES('".$user_name."$','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$email."','".$user_password."');";
    mysql_query($insert_query) or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_close();

    };
      ?>
```

Comment: if you echo $query, what query will be printed ?

Comment: Why have you added this function `sprintf` to your variable '$query'? I would have thought you would want to have something like this: `$query = ("SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE user_name='%s' LIMIT 1");` And at the start do a `$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);` to get the user name and sanitize the input string.

Comment: And then change the initial $query variable into `$query = "SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE user_name='".$user."' LIMIT 1";`

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP 5.3 by the way Mr. Radical.

Comment: @MattMcLaren A *single* person made a slightly snarky comment - not at all any "hate". (I've deleted that comment as not constructive, too). Please try not to generalize a whole community like this. :)

Comment: I apologize. I just haven't received a very warm welcome on the site since I started coding again but you're right, some people have been very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @MattMcLaren is your question solved?

Answer (score 1):

You should put `or die(mysql_error());` in following line:

```
$sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Instead of:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']))or die(mysql_error());
```

Another thing is that you have wrong `if-else` statements.

You code to check which field is empty should be in following `if` statement:

```
if($row||empty($_POST['user_name'])|| empty($_POST['fname'])||empty($_POST['lname'])|| empty($_POST['email'])||empty($_POST['password'])|| empty($_POST['re_password'])||$_POST['password']!=$_POST['re_password']){ 
# if a field is empty, or the passwords don't match make a message
# YOU SHOULD PUT YOUR CODE TO CHECK EMPTY FIELDS SEPARATELY HERE
}
else { 
    # If all fields are not empty, and the passwords match, 
}
```

Comment: Again, doesn't answer question as to why nothing's being sent to DB. Also the code you said to replace with is the same as my original code or was that a mistake? I didn't get what you wanted me to do to change the if else statements because the code is identical. How can I just simplify it, ignore the checking of fields, I just want to hone in on the code that signs up a user, sends data to the DB, that's the issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your check if the user already exists to something like this:

```
if(count($row) > 0)
```

instead of just

```
if($row)
```

Comment: Agreed but still doesn't answer question as to why nothing is being sent to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to test if data gets inserted limit you the code to this:

```
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

    $host=""; // Host name 
    $username=""; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="lurnn"; // Database name 

    /* sanitize post variables */    
    $user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
    $fname =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $lname =     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']); 
    $email =     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $user_password =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 

    /* Database insert query */
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect for insert"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB to insert data");
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO teachers(`user_name`,`f_name`,`l_name`,`email`,`password`) 
VALUES('".$user_name."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$email."','".$user_password."')";
mysql_query($insert_query) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_close();


        };
            ?>
```

MYSQLI_ version:

```
    <?php 


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    $host = "host";
    $user = "user";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "database";   


    /* sanitize post variables */    
    $user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
    $fname =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $lname =     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']); 
    $email =     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $user_password =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 


    // open connection to database
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           //INSERT VALUES INTO DATABASE
           $query = "INSERT INTO teachers(`user_name`,`f_name`,`l_name`,`email`,`password`) 
VALUES('".$user_name."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$email."','".$user_password."')";
         mysqli_query($link,$query)  or die(mysql_error());
         echo var_dump($query);
        }
//close connection to database
        mysqli_close($link);

    };


    ?>
```

If this all fails try the following:

```
    <?php


function submit_form(){
    $host = "";
    $user = "";
    $password = "";
    $database = "";   

    /* sanitize post variables */    
    $user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
    $fname =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $lname =     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']); 
    $email =     mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $user_password =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);


    // open connection to database
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
        IF (!$link){
            echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
        }
        ELSE {
           //INSERT VALUES INTO DATABASE
           $query = "INSERT INTO teachers(`user_name`,`f_name`,`l_name`,`email`,`password`) 
VALUES('".$user_name."','".$fname."','".$lname."','".$email."','".$user_password."')";
         mysqli_query($link,$query)  or die("Insert query failed");
         echo var_dump($query);

        }
//close connection to database
        mysqli_close($link);

    }


$form = <<<EODuserform
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>
        <form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="POST" name="userform">
            <label for='user_name'>Username:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="user_name" id="first" maxlength="25" tabindex='1' VALUE="user_name" /></br>
            <label for='fname'>First Name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="first" maxlength="25" tabindex='2' VALUE="firstname" /></br>
            <label for='lname'>Last Name:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id='lastname' maxlength="25" tabindex='3' VALUE="lastname" /></br>
            <label for='email'>E-mail:</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id='email' maxlength="100" tabindex='4' VALUE="email" /></br>
            <label for='password'>Password:</label></br>
            <input type="password" name="password" id='password' maxlength="25" tabindex='5' VALUE="password" /></br>
            <label for='re-password'>Re-type password:</label></br>
            <input type="password" name="re-password" id='re-password' maxlength="25" tabindex='6' VALUE="re-password" /></br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" tabindex='6' />
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
EODuserform;


IF(!IsSet($_POST['submit'])){ // Check if form is not send, if not display empty form.

    echo $form;
}

ELSE{
// in the case you want to send something to the database use 
submit_form();
echo ('Thanks for submitting your form');
}

?>
```

Comment: I tried bottom code and got back a bunch of error messages that I can't fit here. Try signing up at lurnn.com/signup.html and you'll see all the error messages.

Comment: @MattMcLaren you forgot to post the errors. B.T.W. I think I might have solved the error. Try again I remove double quotation marks in `mysql_connect`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help it's much appreciated. I used to be able to code this in five seconds but apparently a lot has changed in the past year.

Comment: It says this for lines 10-14: 
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/88/10880688/html/verify.php on line 10

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/content/88/10880688/html/verify.php on line 10

Comment: @MattMcLaren things change the always do, but I am sure that you will be able to get back into the game.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix the issue? I'm lost.

Comment: Same error messages. When you say CONNECT TO THE DATABASE HERE do you want me to add code to connect again there?

Comment: I put this under #connect to the database here: mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); and got the following error message, this time only one: Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/content/88/10880688/html/verify.php on line 4
cannot connect. Do I need to put the DB connection under the variables???

Comment: No you shouldn't do that you should only replace the text inside the quotes with your host, username, password and database name.

Comment: Still getting same error messages. Try for yourself at lurnn.com/signup.html

Comment: The good news is it is finally sending to the DB but I'm still getting these error messages and I'm not sure WHICH try sent the data to the DB. JUST CHECKED. It was a previous incarnation, probably when it was lingering on verify.php.

Comment: FYI in the database the values are user_name, fname, lname, email, password in the teacher table.

Comment: Do you have skype I'll give you the correct answer if you figure this out, I'll even pay you this is driving me crazy it shouldn't take up so many hours of my life. At some point, your code worked, I think it just didn't include a redirect to the index.html page and I think that's when it actually worked and sent the data to the DB. I just don't know which code it was that had it linger on verify.php.